# plot two series in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, graph, numerical-methods

I would want to graph the values of `r1` and `r2` in one plot, how can I do it?

```
for i=1:10
r1=rand(1)
r2=max(rand(1,2))
end
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think that r1=rand(1) should be r1(i) = rand(1), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many, many ways, here is one that exposes a few options:

```
clc;
clear all, close all;

r1 = zeros(10, 1);
r2 = zeros(10, 1);
x = 1:10;

for i=1:10
    r1(i) = rand(1);
    r2(i) = max(rand(1,2));
end

figure('Name', 'Values of r1 and r2', 'NumberTitle', 'off');
hold on;
axis([0, 11, -0.5, 1.5])
plot(x, r1, '+', x, r2,'o'); %many possibilities and options here for line style
h = legend('r1', 'r2');
xlabel('index')
ylabel('value')

disp('press a key');
pause();
close all;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i=1:10
r1(i)=rand(1)
r2(i)=max(rand(1,2))
end
plot(r1)
hold on 
plot (r2)
```